# How can I print a Java applet in a web page?

Tags: java, printing, applet

I've searching and I didn't find nothing that worked.

The problem is that I have a Java applet with some text field, labels, and text área. This applet is in a HTML page with the tag   etc and I want to print the content of the applet as if it was a Word or pdf. the applet.

I have tried pdfcrowd and similar and I didn't get it maybe I didn't use the good way.

Is it possible to print the applet and how?

Thanks